# How to get Json data into listview for windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have Json links and i need to get the data into listview. listview consists of picture, Itemname and Price. I m using Newtonsoft.Json. I need to pass headers(username, password,..) and then call the menuitem link into my application to access the menuitem data. I have many items in this listview to display. I am giving only one example below for Json data. Pls suggest me any good information as i am new to json. Thank you.

{"data":[{"Menuitemid":1,"Menucategoryid":1,"Itemname":"Hot And Spicy Chicken Wings","Description":"About Hot And Spicy Chicken Wings","Price":12.0,"Picture":"http://www.ownboughtearned.com/demo/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/small_thumbnail.png","Thumbnail":null,"Active":true}]}

/

```
/Listbox binding in xaml

  <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" SelectionChanged="lstItems_SelectionChanged" CharacterSpacing="-1" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1.2" BorderBrush="Silver" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="440">
                            <Grid Margin="0 10 0 10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <!--<RowDefinition Height="*" />-->
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="105" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                    <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />-->
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Silver" CornerRadius="3" Height="97" 
                                            Width="97" Background="White">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Picture}" Stretch="Fill"
                                           Height="95" Width="95" />
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Itemname}" MaxWidth="290" Margin="13 0 0 0" 
                                           FontSize="25" Foreground="#5b261e" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="None" 
                                           Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">

                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=Price}" 
                                           FontSize="20" Foreground="#5b261e" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

---

```
 //MenuRepository.cs
    namespace  MenuInfo.Concrete
{
    public class MenuRepository : IMenuRepository
    {
       public  List<MenuItem> listitems = new List<MenuItem>();
        public List<MenuItem> ListMenus()
        {          
            System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri("http://xxxxxxxxxx.testshell.net/api/restaurant/menuitems/1");

             System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Headers["username"] = "info@xxxxxxxxxx.com";
            httpWebRequest.Headers["password"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


            httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(OnGetResponseCompleted, httpWebRequest);     


            return listitems;
        }
        private async void  OnGetResponseCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

                var response = httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(ar);           

                var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MenuItemObject));
                var responseObject = (MenuItemObject)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());         

                foreach (MenuItem loc in responseObject.data)
                {

                    listitems.Add(loc);

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }     

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this if you do use Newtonsoft.Json?  I was just able to add it to a new WP8 project using NuGet.  You may need to upgrade your NuGet installer if you are having problems.

Comment: tools -> extensions and updates

Comment: @SeeSharp bingo! i updated NuGet installer. tools -> extensions and updates ->updates. Thank u See Sharp.

Comment: @madhukumar can you pls display your itemtemplate

Comment: @madhukumar are you using List or Observable COllection

Comment: using list not ObservableCollection

Comment: @techloverr still not working.

Comment: @ShawnKendrot I am not getting data into the listview. If i debug i can see that json is working and all the list items are seen in "listitems.Add(loc);".

Comment: @madhukumar have you used observable collection?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem stems from the fact that you are returning an empty collection from the `ListMenus` method. The method will return before it has a chance to populate the collection within the `OnGetResponseCompleted` callback. You can get around this in one of two ways. The first is to change you `listitems` variable to be an ObservableCollection.

```
public  ICollection<MenuItem> listitems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
```

With this approach you will continue to return an empty collection, but when you add items to it within the OnGetResponseCompleted method, it will notify the ListBox that an item was added (provided that you set the ITemsSource to be the result of the ListMenus method. Doing it this way has negative performance impacts. For each item that you add, it notifies the UI to update rather than one big update with all of the items. It is also likely that it will throw an exception that you are trying to update a UI component when not on the UI thread. The callback  OnGetResponseCompleted will likely be on a separate thread.

Another, and better approach would be to return the results using the async/await pattern. You could use the new HttpClient class to do this, but if you like using a WebRequest, you can still accomplish this using a TaskCompletionSource.

```
public Task<IList<MenuItem>> ListMenus()
{
    var completion = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<MenuItem>>();
    System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri("http://xxxxxxxxxx.testshell.net/api/restaurant/menuitems/1");

    System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Headers["username"] = "info@xxxxxxxxxx.com";
    httpWebRequest.Headers["password"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var response = httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(ar))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var responseObject =
                            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuItemObject>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                        foreach (MenuItem loc in responseObject.data)
                        {
                            listitems.Add(loc);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            completion.SetResult(listitems);
        }, null);


    return completion.Task;
}
```

With this approach, you would await the result of the ListMenus and set the ItemsSource from it.

```
lstItems.ItemsSource = await ListMenus();
```

Now you get the results populated, and do not have the performance impact of adding items one at a time.